# Problems with BibLaTex and Biber on MacOS

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, texmaker, macos

I'm currently writing a seminar paper with TexMaker (Version 5.0.4) on macOS Catalina (10.15.5).

I tried to switch from BibTex to BibLaTex due to formatting issues for my bibliography (I need APA style in German). With BibTex and the \apalike style, the bibliography is in English while I (obvs) need it to be in German.

So, with the help of a friend who is more familiar with the program, we encounter a problem switching to BibLaTex.

The following is an example for the preamble + a sample citation:

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{color} \usepackage[a4paper,lmargin={1in},rmargin={1in}, tmargin={1in},bmargin = {1in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-apa}
\addbibresource{Bib}
\listfiles


\newcommand{\source}[1]{\caption*{Quelle: {#1}}}

\expandafter\def\expandafter\quote\expandafter{\quote\small}
\usepackage{hyphenat}

\begin{document}

This is my citation 1 \cite{clasen2012instrument}. 

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Literatur}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

If I try to run pdfLatex --> Biber --> pdfLatex I get the following error:

INFO - This is Biber 2.14 INFO - Logfile is 'BibLaTex-Test.blg' INFO - Reading 'BibLaTex-Test.bcf' INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0 INFO - Processing section 0 INFO - Globbing data source 'Bib' INFO - Globbed data source 'Bib' to Bib INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'Bib' for section 0

**ERROR - Cannot find 'Bib'! INFO - ERRORS: 1**

The .log file:

`biblatex.sty    2019/12/01 v3.14 programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)`

The .blg file:

```
[0] Config.pm:304> INFO - This is Biber 2.14 
 [0] Config.pm:307> INFO - Logfile is 'BibLaTex-Test.blg'
[102] biber-darwin:322> INFO - === Wed Jul  8, 2020, 19:00:42
[123] Biber.pm:415> INFO - Reading 'BibLaTex-Test.bcf'
[278] Biber.pm:943> INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
[297] Biber.pm:4256> INFO - Processing section 0
[298] Utils.pm:75> INFO - Globbing data source 'Bib'
[298] Utils.pm:91> INFO - Globbed data source 'Bib' to Bib
[310] Biber.pm:4455> INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'Bib' for section 0
[506] Utils.pm:320> ERROR - Cannot find 'Bib'!
[506] Biber.pm:132> INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

This is the best it's been for a few hours now after we tried it in a new "test" file.

I am a newbie to LaTex, my friend is a bit better but at his wits end too.

Why do I get this error? (Is it Biber, MacOs, am I dumb?)

If you need any more infomartion I'm happy to help.

PS.: If anyone has another solution for my bibliography formatting problem with German APA citation style, I'm happy to hear that too!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to specify the file extension of your `.bib` file: Instead of `\addbibresource{Bib}` try `\addbibresource{Bib.bib}`.

Comment: Hey @AlanMunn, thx for your tip.
It worked. thought I didn't need it because Bibtex doesn't need it but Biber does.

Edit: I'm so relieved rn! Thanks a lot! You saved my sanity!

Comment: Off-topic: Do make life a bit easier on yourself and replace `lmargin={1in},rmargin={1in}, tmargin={1in},bmargin = {1in}` with `margin=1in`.

Comment: @Mico so obvious... ouch... thx a lot!